# prepareForSegue Being performed before Button action

Tags: ios, json, uitableview, segue, viewcontroller

I am new to IOS and trying to figure this out.

I am trying to pass json data from one View controller to other(TableViewcontroller) and I want the button action(this has the json data) to be performed before the prepareForSegue method(which then passes json data which I got from button action) to TableViewcontroller.

But my preparesegue method is performed first before button action and tableview gets no data ?

But when i click the button for the second time i am getting the tableview json data.

This happens when I try to pass Textfield to URl not if i use the direct url.

Can Someone Please help me with this. 
Also let me know if there is any other way to do this.

Here is the code in first VC:

```
- (IBAction)buttonShow:(id)sender {

NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Some API URL=%@",self.ingredientTextfield.text];

NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:urlString];
req = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:url];

NSURLSessionDataTask *datatask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:req completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
    NSString *rcCount = [json objectForKey:@"count"];
    NSLog(@"Recipe Count : %@",rcCount);
    NSMutableDictionary *recipedata = [json objectForKey:@"recipes"];
    NSLog(@"Recipe data : %@",recipedata);


    NSMutableArray *titlearray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for (NSMutableDictionary *singlerecipedata in recipedata) {
        NSString *title = [singlerecipedata objectForKey:@"title"];
        NSLog(@"Recipe title : %@",title);
        [titlearray addObject:title];
        NSLog(@"tittlearray : %@",titlearray);

    }
    actualDataArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:titlearray];

    NSLog(@"tittle array inside for:%@",actualDataArray);

}];
NSLog(@"tittle array outside :%@",actualDataArray);

[datatask resume];
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueIdentifier" sender:sender];  

}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if  ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"segueIdentifier"]) {

        RecipesTableViewController *new = [segue destinationViewController];
        NSLog(@"in segue :%@",actualDataArray);
        [new setMyrecipeTittleArray:actualDataArray];
    }

}
```

Comment: can you please provide some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because `NSURLSessionDataTask` is *asynchronous*. As such, the data will not be retrieved at the point at which you're calling:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueIdentifier" sender:sender];
```

To explain things more clearly, this is the sequence of events:

1. "Start the HTTP request": `[datatask resume];`
2. "Perform segue": `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueIdentifier" sender:sender];`
3. And then your data is downloaded at some point later, in the callback/completion block:

   ```
   NSMutableArray *titlearray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
   for (NSMutableDictionary *singlerecipedata in recipedata) {
       // ...
   } 
   actualDataArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:titlearray];
   ```

... at which point your segue has already been performed.

To solve this, you can do one of two things:

**My preferred method, because it *feels* faster to the user (albeit this is much more challenging to implement):**

1. Implement a delegate protocol and method on your master view controller that notifies the child (table) when the data task has finished
2. Implement some sort of loading indicator (e.g. `UIActivityIndicator`)
3. Make the child (table) the master's delegate
4. When the delegate method is called, have the child update itself (e.g. `[tableView reloadData]`)

This has the benefit of immediately performing the segue, which feels faster to the user, and asynchronously (non-blockingly) presents the data when available. You can even be super slick and implement some error checking and present out-of-the-way notifications when the data fails to load or if the network times out.

**The other way, which is easier to implement, but has some major drawbacks:**

Move your `performSegue` call inside the completion block of the data task:

```
NSMutableArray *titlearray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for (NSMutableDictionary *singlerecipedata in recipedata) {
    // ...
} 
actualDataArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:titlearray];
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueIdentifier" sender:sender];
```

The biggest drawback of this is that it will feel slow to the user. Even with a great connection, there's now probably a 100-500ms delay between when the button is pressed and the segue is performed. On a slow or unresponsive network connection, the segue may not be performed for several seconds. This frustrates users.

Answer (score 1):

Place Prepare for Segue Between Your For Loop, then using Breakpoints you can check Result !!

Your Code Must be:

```
- (IBAction)buttonShow:(id)sender {

NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Some API URL=%@",self.ingredientTextfield.text];

NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:urlString];
req = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:url];

NSURLSessionDataTask *datatask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:req completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
    NSString *rcCount = [json objectForKey:@"count"];
    NSLog(@"Recipe Count : %@",rcCount);
    NSMutableDictionary *recipedata = [json objectForKey:@"recipes"];
    NSLog(@"Recipe data : %@",recipedata);


    NSMutableArray *titlearray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for (NSMutableDictionary *singlerecipedata in recipedata) {
        NSString *title = [singlerecipedata objectForKey:@"title"];
        NSLog(@"Recipe title : %@",title);
        [titlearray addObject:title];
        NSLog(@"tittlearray : %@",titlearray);

    }
    actualDataArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:titlearray];
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueIdentifier" sender:sender];  
    NSLog(@"tittle array inside for:%@",actualDataArray);

}];
NSLog(@"tittle array outside :%@",actualDataArray);

[datatask resume];

}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if  ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"segueIdentifier"]) {

        RecipesTableViewController *new = [segue destinationViewController];
        NSLog(@"in segue :%@",actualDataArray);
        [new setMyrecipeTittleArray:actualDataArray];
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks @ shikha kochar. But this gave me Error : NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIKeyboardTaskQueue waitUntilAllTasksAreFinished] may only be called from the main thread.After adding performSegueWithIdentifier to mainthread using NSOperation i am able to populate the tableview but there is a lag between button click and updated tableview.

Answer (score 0):

If the performSegueWithIdentifier method is called in the IBAction buttonTapped:(id)sender method, then prepareForSegue will necessarily be called after buttonTapped is called. As an example, look at this code :

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

- (IBAction)goButtonTapped:(id)sender;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *buttonButton;


@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"PrepareForSegue called");
}

- (IBAction)goButtonTapped:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"Button tapped %@", [sender description]);
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SegueToTabs" sender:nil];

}
@end
```

This yields the following messages in the console :

```
2016-04-05 21:41:46.300 GUITesting[67708:5496161] Button tapped <UIButton: 0x7fbd4411f010; frame = (20 62; 374 30); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fbd4411b2f0>>
2016-04-05 21:41:46.304 GUITesting[67708:5496161] prepareForSegue called
```

So perhaps you are doing something else in the code which is causing your prepareForSegue to be called before your buttonTapped.

Btw, if you wanted to send some object along in the prepareForSegue to the next VC, you could simply set it as a a property of the targetVC in the prepareForSegue method.